# Amazon MSK: Error loading connectors. API response: Network Failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-msk

I try to add AWS Connectors, however I got this error when I open the Amazon MSK -> MSK Connect -> Connectors page:

> Error loading connectors
>
> This operation cannot be completed at this time due to a network
> failure. For more information and in order to mitigate the issue, see
> Troubleshooting  in the AWS Management Console guide. If the problem
> persists, contact AWS customer support.
>
> API response: Network Failure

[image]

And I have [AmazonMSKFullAccess](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-managed-policy/latest/reference/AmazonMSKFullAccess.html) access.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The network failure error is misleading, and `AmazonMSKFullAccess` is not enough.

After adding this to permissions policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "kafkaconnect:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

and grant to my account. The error is gone. Hope it helps!